# How to fix 'ERROR ON PAGE: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: require' - NodeJS with Sinon.js

Tags: node.js, sinon

- I have problem with test cases running. actually I upgrade node dependency from old version to new version also node version v6 to v10,  Before update npm module my code was working fine. But I do not known what issue happen now. 
  Please help me out that..!

Comment: Please, read rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and modify your question. Put here your code then we can try to reproduce and fix it. Otherwise I can just tell that there is something wrong with your code.

Comment: Do not put screenshots (if you are not showing some graphical issue) put your code here. Only then we can copy/paste and run/check. Do you think many people will try type all you dependencies manually? You just preventing people from helping you.

Comment: My project structure is so big and lots of configuration is there...

Comment: I just telling you that most likely you won't get response for your question, and may be some will think of it as off-topic or incorrect and request to close it. If you have a lot of code you can upload it to some repository and share the link, or make it simple and provide minimal code.... But enough off-topic comments from me, you got my point.